# Orion constellation shape

Tags: space, night-sky, constellations, orion

In textbook **"Orion constellation the four bright stars appear to be arranged in the form of a quadrilateral"** and I found in internet when I searched *"Four stars Rigel, Betelgeuse, Bellatrix, and Saiph form a large roughly **rectangular** shape"* Here is my doubt I did not find any rectangular or quadrilateral shape and how can those stars form a **rectangular** shape or **quadrilateral** shape? Could you clarify and show me with a diagram or picture of that rectangular or quadrilateral shape of those stars?

Comment: How can four stars form anything else but a quadrilateral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just look at how Orion looks in the Sky. I added the lines in yellow showing the (slightly deformed rectangle) based on this [image by By Mouser on Wikipedia CC-BY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_(constellation)#/media/File:Orion_3008_huge.jpg): [image: Orion] while the white lines are the usual lines used to denote the outline of Orion. Upper left is Betelgeuze, lower right is Rigel, upper right is Bellatrix, lower left is Saiph.

Comment: Thank you very much sir...